# Firebase validation of dynamic child key

Tags: validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Suppose I have the following data structure:

```
users {
    "GSlxbK0iBYC30d1LDnIaMmERFa6" {
        "friends": {
            "H2JBkBgiGx1QCn2D4Ku6ZEKpuYu": true,
            "45iOj1Ak4Y7PmxHqcnR2I4DfMBS": true,
            "KFhzQdJZOPn9g3vAJLUo4MSTkBa": true
        }
    }
}
```

The 'users' keys and 'friends' keys are auth.uid GUIDs. I'd like to validate, under 'friends', that the child values are booleans only.

I have tried the following:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$user_id": {
            ".read": "newData.child($user_id).val() == auth.uid",
            ".write": "newData.child($user_id).val() == auth.uid",

            "friends": {
                ".validate": "newData.child($friend_id).isBoolean()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am the following error returned when attempting to Publish:

```
Error saving rules – Line 8: Unknown variable '$friend_id'.
```

Is there a way to refer to leaf keys as variables?

I updated the rule as follows to try and work around this, which did Publish successfully:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$user_id": {
            ".read": "newData.child($user_id).val() == auth.uid",
            ".write": "newData.child($user_id).val() == auth.uid",

            "friends": {
                ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when running the Simulator, it fails on the validate line with this error:

```
Line 8 (/users/GSlxbK0iBYC30d1LDnIaMmERFa6/friends)
validate: "newData.isBoolean()"
```

I am a bit confused even after reading the documentation what exactly this validation rule is evaluating and why it fails given my dataset contains boolean leaf values.

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but you're validating one level too high. Since you want to validate the friend ID itself, you need to define the validation in its `$friendid` node:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$user_id": {
            ".read": "newData.child($user_id).val() == auth.uid",
            ".write": "newData.child($user_id).val() == auth.uid",

            "friends": {
                "$friendId": {
                    ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```